# 403 Forbidden error on setting Apache Wamp Directory alias in windows 8

Tags: wamp, alias

I have created a directory alias in wamp 2.5 in windows 8. But I am getting 403 forbidden error when trying to access the folders in the directory from url.

My alias file is:

```
Alias /test/ "D:\work\www\test/" 

<Directory "D:\work\www\test/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Apache manual

```
Note that if you include a trailing / on the URL-path then the server 
will require a trailing / in order to expand the alias. That is, if you use

Alias /icons/ /usr/local/apache/icons/

then the URL /icons will not be aliased, as it lacks that trailing /.    
Likewise, if you omit the slash on the URL-path then you must 
also omit it from the file-path.
```

So change

```
Alias /test/ "D:\work\www\test/"
```

To

```
Alias /test "D:/work/www/test"
```